# Express js Redirect not rendering page

Tags: express, redirect

I am trying to redirect the user that uses my website after he has logged into his account, he will be redirected to a dashboard.
The problem is that I can see a request for the `/dashboard` route in the Network tab of the browser Inspection Tools, but the page never loads.
This is my code so far.

```
router.post('/login', function(request, response){
    // verify against database and send back response
    var userData = {};
    userData.email = request.body.email;
    userData.password = request.body.password;
    userData.rememberPassword = request.body.rememberPassword;

    // check if in the database and re-route
    var query = database.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [userData.email], function(error, result){
        if(error){
            console.log('Error ', error);
        }
        if(result.length){
            // check if the password is correct
            if(userData.password === result[0].password){
                // redirect to the dashboard
                // TODO this piece of code does not redirect correctly
                response.redirect('/dashboard'); // < HERE
                console.log('Haha');
            }
        }
        else{
            // do something when there is are no results
            // invalid email status code
            response.statusCode = 405;
            response.send('');
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the route towards the `dashboard`, and it is being rendered properly when accessed in the browser.

```
router.get('/dashboard', function(request, response){
    response.render(path.resolve(__dirname, 'views', 'dashboard.pug'));
});
```

Why can't it redirect when the user completes the login process?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be in the frontend and not in the backend. If you are using AJAX to send the **POST** request, it is specifically designed to not change your url.

Use `window.location.href` after AJAX's request has completed to update the URL with the desired path.But the easiest way would be to create a form with action as `/login` and use the submission to trigger the url change.

To make sure that the problem does not lie with the backend,

1. Add a logging statement to `router.get('/dashboard'` to verify if
   the control was passed.
2. Check that the HTTP status code of the /login route is 302 indicating a redirect and location header has the route /dashboard.
3. Content type of response /dashboard is text/html.If not please set it using `res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")`.